# Show/hide div and clear filed value when change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some div that will show depending on the select value. Suppose there are two input fields name 'Apartment and Bechelor' If I select 'Apartment' some div and select field will show related to the apartment. The problem I am facing is, I can't clear the field value when selecting another. Like, after selecting 'Apartment', I will select Bachelor. Now it should be clear the value of the field which was under the apartment so that If I again select 'Apartment', I will get default values or clean fields.

```
<div id="residential" >
   <input type="radio" value="apartment" id="type_apartment" name="type"  >
   <label for="type_apartment" class="radio-inline"> Apartment/Flat </label>
   <input type="radio" value="bachelor" id="type_bachelor" name="type">
   <label for="type_bachelor" class="radio-inline"> Bechelor  </label>
</div>
<!-- show this when apartment select -->
<div class="form-group " id="tenant-flat">
   <select id="tenant-type" class="form-control" name="tenant">
      <option value="">Anyone</option>
      <option  value="family">Family</option>
      <option value="bechelor" >Bechelor</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group " id="flat-type">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
      <select id="" class="form-control" name="flat-type">
         <option value="">Select Flat Type</option>
         <option value="sublet" >Sublet</option>
         <option value="full-flat" >Full Flat</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- show this when bechelor select -->
<div class="form-group " id="r-type">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
      <select id="room" class="form-control" name="room_type">
         <option value="">Select Room Type</option>
         <option value="seat">Seat</option>
         <option value="room" >Room</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group " id="tenant">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
      <select id="" class="form-control" name="tenant">
         <option value="">Select Member</option>
         <option value="family" >Family</option>
         <option value="student" >Student</option>
         <option value="job-holder" >Job Holder</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#r-type').hide();
      $('#tenant').hide();
      $('#tenant-flat').hide();
       $('#flat-type').hide();
    
      $('.pretty input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
         if($(this).attr('value') == 'apartment'){
            $('#tenant-flat').show();
         }
         else{
            $('#flat-type').hide();
         }
      });
      
      var showDiv = document.getElementById("tenant-type");
      showDiv.onchange = function(){
            var hiddenDiv = document.getElementById("flat-type");
            hiddenDiv.style.display = (this.value == "family") ? "block":"none";
            var genderDiv = document.getElementById("gender");
            genderDiv.style.display = (this.value == "bechelor") ? "block":"none";
      };
   
      
   
      $('.pretty input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
         if($(this).attr('value') == 'bachelor' || $(this).attr('value') == 'sublet' || $(this).attr('value') == 'hostel' ){
            $('#r-type').show();
            $('#tenant').show();
          
            $('#tenant-type').hide();
   
         }
         else{
            $('#r-type').hide();
            $('#tenant').hide();
            $('#tenant-type').show();
           
   
         }
      });
   
   });
</script>
```

Comment: by *I will get default values or clean fields.* you want to reset the dropdown fields or want what user selected before toggling between apartment/Bachelor?

Comment: user select before toggling. Suppose a user selects apartment. Then the user will get a form which is under the apartment where will be select option, radio button, checkbox, input fields . After fill up the infomration, if the user select bechelor, then all the previous fields will be cleared which was filled by the user under apartment. Same case for bechelor also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to reset the dropdown options you can set the value of the select elements `selectIndex` property to 0 with this line:
`$('.form-control').prop('selectedIndex', 0);`
and in your code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#r-type').hide();
    $('#tenant').hide();
    $('#tenant-flat').hide();
     $('#flat-type').hide();
     
     $('#residential input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
         if($(this).attr('value') == 'apartment'){
            $('#tenant-flat').show();
            $('#flat-type').show();
            $('#r-type').hide();
            $('#tenant').hide();
         }
         else{
            $('#r-type').show();
            $('#tenant').show();
            $('#flat-type').hide();
            $('#tenant-flat').hide();
         }

         $('.form-control').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
      });

    $('#tenent-type').on('change', function() {
      if($('#flat-type').val =='family') {
        $('#flat-type').show();
      } else {
        $('#flat-type').hide();
      }
      
      if($('#gender').val =='bechelor') {
        $('#gender').show();
      } else {
        $('#gender').hide();
      }
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="residential" >
   <input type="radio" value="apartment" id="type_apartment" name="type"  >
   <label for="type_apartment" class="radio-inline"> Apartment/Flat </label>
   <input type="radio" value="bachelor" id="type_bachelor" name="type">
   <label for="type_bachelor" class="radio-inline"> Bechelor  </label>
</div>
<!-- show this when apartment select -->
<div class="form-group " id="tenant-flat">
   <select id="tenant-type" class="form-control" name="tenant">
      <option value="">Anyone</option>
      <option  value="family">Family</option>
      <option value="bechelor" >Bechelor</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group " id="flat-type">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
      <select id="" class="form-control" name="flat-type">
         <option value="">Select Flat Type</option>
         <option value="sublet" >Sublet</option>
         <option value="full-flat" >Full Flat</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- show this when bechelor select -->
<div class="form-group " id="r-type">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
      <select id="room" class="form-control" name="room_type">
         <option value="">Select Room Type</option>
         <option value="seat">Seat</option>
         <option value="room" >Room</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group " id="tenant">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
      <select id="" class="form-control" name="tenant">
         <option value="">Select Member</option>
         <option value="family" >Family</option>
         <option value="student" >Student</option>
         <option value="job-holder" >Job Holder</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. What if to reset the input (text, radio, and checkbox) field?

Comment: happy I could help. if that was the answer you were looking for I'll be happy if you could check it as such. in regard to your question here in the comment - what do you mean by resetting the input radio or checkbox field?

Comment: by _to reset the dropdown options_ this, I understand it is only for select tags or field. If there is input tag like radio button, checkbox etc, what should I have to do?

Comment: radio buttons and checkboxes have a `checked` attribute you can turn to false or remove like so: `$('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');`  you will probably find for each input type the right way to reset it in here if you'll search "reset <element>"

Comment: Thanks. I got my result.